# Is it a hard or soft delete on comments, what about the data dump?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, deleted-comments, deleted-posts

Recently I figured out deleting a post is really a soft delete and it is still in the DB, unless of course there are enough votes to make a hard delete.  I'm curious if comments are a soft or hard delete.  You don't get a vote to delete option either.

Finally, are soft deleted items included in the data dump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted items are not included in the data dump.

From Comment: comments are a soft delete...

Comment: Thanks.... don't you ever sleep?